# What max_execution_time can one rely on?

Tags: php

Different hosts have different php.ini settings for `max_execution_time`. When coding a potentially long-running script for a server you don't control (or a hosting environment has not been decided upon yet), what number of seconds can be considered a safe minimum?

Comment: Target 5 seconds - any more than that and users will be complaining about a slow site anyway.... any request that takes longer than that should be farmed off to a background process

Comment: `When coding a potentially long-running script for a server you don't control` how long are you expecting your script to run for? There you will find your answer...

Comment: @MarkBaker I disagree. What if it's not for your users, but for you? To update a database, to parse a giant JSON from a slow API to your database? There are many occasions in which you would want the execution time higher than 30 seconds.

Comment: @Mave - If you have tasks that take that long, then you should really be running them from the command line, not via a browser

Comment: @MarkBaker, that's true, but most shared hosting doesn't allow for CLI access.

Comment: In practical terms when running from a browser, webservers also have timeouts that can add to the complications (Apache default is 300 seconds IIRC); but any web-based interaction is subject to other interruptions and can't be relied on

Comment: @MarkBaker I agree, however, simple hosting does not give you access to any console. Consoles can bug out too. Nothing is ever completely secure from error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for php.ini is:

> max_execution_time:   "30"

http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

So, unless the host has decreased this which I wouldn't think they would - I would aim for that. Although it's complete guess work when you don't control the target server.

Answer (score 0):

I would go based on how long you expect something to run. If your script normally takes about `45 secs` to process then you can set a `max_execution_time` to `60` to be safe.

It all depends on you. I have a social networking site that is script intensive and runs crons etc so my `max_execution_time` is kinda high to ensure I have no timeouts.

You may be able to set it using a `php.ini` file in your root or also in the `.htaccess` file if you don't have access to the `main php.ini` file. Depending on the host.

If you use .htaccess you can do this and increase the default value.

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value max_execution_time 259200
</IfModule>
```

Or in php.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Answer (score -1):

You can **change the max_execution_time**, using the **set_time_limit** function (only if php is **not running in safe mode**).
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php
**The default max_execution_time is 30 seconds**.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time